# Method to read a XML

Tags: c#, xml, methods

i created a method to read a xml file but it doesn't work twice, i have to place the pointer at start of the file but I didn't found how.

```
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;
using System.Diagnostics;



namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    class Class {
    private System.Xml.XmlReader XML_File;
    public void DebugXML() 
        {
            this.XML_File.Read();
            while (!this.XML_File.EOF)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(this.XML_File.ReadOuterXml());
            }
        }


 public Class()
        {
            AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection("Data Source=MyComputer;InitialCatalog=Database");
            conn.Open();
            AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand("Select Hierarchize([Projects].[Project Branch].Levels(1).Members) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME, HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME, CUSTOM_ROLLUP, UNARY_OPERATOR, KEY0 ON 0, Hierarchize({{{[Period Calculations].[Period].&[0]}, {[Period Calculations].[Period].&[1]}, {[Period Calculations].[Period].&[2]}, {[Period Calculations].[Period].&[3]}, {[Period Calculations].[Period].&[4]}, {[Period Calculations].[Period].&[5]}}}) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME, HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME, CUSTOM_ROLLUP, UNARY_OPERATOR, KEY0 ON 1 FROM [ProjectControl] WHERE ([Measures].[WIP]) CELL PROPERTIES BACK_COLOR, CELL_ORDINAL, FORE_COLOR, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS, FORMAT_STRING, VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, UPDATEABLE", conn);
            CellSet Cellules = cmd.ExecuteCellSet();
            this.XML_File = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
            DebugXML();
            DebugXML();
            conn.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us the type of `XML_File`, or why you need to keep it open in the class instead of reading it separately each time.

Comment: `XmlReader` is a forward-only reader. You'll need to use some other construct if you want to read it multiple times.

Comment: System.Xml.XmlReader XML_File;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you execute your code twice, the second time you'll an exception telling you that the file is opened by anothe process.

So that means that you didn't ... close it. So close it !

Comment: Sure, I tried it but behind that is a heavy query so i would like to avoid execute it each time.

Comment: ?? what do you mean ? what do you want to do ? what's the link between your question and this "heavy query" you got a be more specific

Comment: I precised my question, and to be more specific, I use a web service to retrieve data from a Cube (Analysis Services) and I would like to stock the XML or the Celldata somewhere I can access in my MainApplication.

Comment: then save your xml file on the disk and read this file (use a XmlWriter)

Answer (score 0):

Also, look at the [Microsoft Support Article - How to read XML file by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548) which has the following example.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ReadXMLfromFile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Class1.
    /// </summary>
    class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader ("books.xml");
            while (reader.Read()) 
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType) 
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                        Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                        Console.WriteLine (reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                        Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```